# Parameter passing in an MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following ActionResult in my controller

```
            [HttpGetAttribute]
    public ActionResult _UpdateAlertNote(int recordId)
    {
        DealActionUpdateAlertNoteViewModel vm = new DealActionUpdateAlertNoteViewModel();

        dtDeal_v10_r1.Manager objMan = new dtDeal_v10_r1.Manager(ref mobjSecurity);
        dtDeal_v10_r1.Deal objDeal = default(dtDeal_v10_r1.Deal);

        objDeal = objMan.GetDealObject(recordId, true);

        vm.Message = objDeal.AlertMessage;
        vm.IsDefaultStyle = objDeal.Alert_UseDefaultStyle;
        vm.BackgroundColor = objDeal.Alert_BackgroundColor;
        vm.FontColor = objDeal.Alert_FontColor;
        vm.DealId = recordId;

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

Also the following ActionResult

```
            [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _UpdateAlertNote(DealActionUpdateAlertNoteViewModel vm)
    {
        dtDeal_v10_r1.Manager objMan = new dtDeal_v10_r1.Manager(ref mobjSecurity);

        objMan.UpdateAlertMessage(vm.DealId, vm.Message, vm.IsDefaultStyle, vm.FontColor, vm.BackgroundColor);

        return this.PartialView("_action", vm.DealId);

    }
```

When I execute this code it the "DealId" comes up as 0 in the Post.

I checked the Get and the DealId is being stored in the vm.DealId but is not passed through to the Post method.

I am not sure why it isn't passing could someone help me out with this.

****EDIT json added***

```
    DealerSocket.TakeAction.updateDealAlertNote = function () {
var controller = "/DealAction/_UpdateAlertNote?mDeal_ID=";
var formId = "_UpdateDealAlertNoteFormElement";

DealerSocket.TakeAction.PostActionAndRefresh(formId, controller);
```

};

Comment: How are you calling the POST Action? is it an Ajax call?

Comment: Actually the post code that I have is part of an onclick event that fires an ajax call.

Comment: You need to populate and send a Json object representing the DealActionUpdateAlertNoteViewModel class. That's the piece you need to post so we can help.

Comment: Please see the edits

Comment: Is the vm.DealId stored in a form element in the form you are posting? Like in a value of a hidden element or something? something like: <input type="hidden" value="@vm.DealId" /> within the Form tag.

Comment: No it is not stored in the form itself.  It comes in from another view as this view is a partial view.  I am thinking this may be the issue then

Comment: Yep, you need that value to be in the form to be included in the Post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are posting an HTML Form element to a POST action, you need to make sure the value you pass to the view is stored in a Form element.

In this case of yours you will need something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@vm.DealId" />
```

within the `<form>` tag that you are Posting to the action.

Only elements inside the `<form>` tag will be serialized and sent to the Action.